# Ждущий режим - не работает клавиатура и мышь. Arch Linux

Tags: linux, archlinux, bios

После выхода из ждущего режима перестает работать клавиатура и мышка, помогает только полное выключение ПК. Я так понимаю, перестают работать все usb устройства. Как можно это исправить, чтобы клавиатура и мышь после выхода из ждущего режима снова работали? Также хотелось бы отключить led индикатор на корпусе при переходе в энергосберегающий режим (В bios копался там такого нет). Модель материнки: Asus P9D-X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтоб usb устройство ресетилось после сна попробуй добавить  `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` в строку запуска ядра https://askubuntu.com/a/1056420/179720

"отключить led индикатор" - в биосе есть настройки глубины спящего режима s1-s4 - попробуй поменять режимы.

Comment: У меня usb устройства не ресетаются при использовании `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` также не помог скрипт в `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/reset-mouse`. Я решил изменить настройку в BIOS `ACPI Sleep State` - `S3 only(Syspend to RAM)` на `Suspend Disabled`. ПК не выключается при переходе в ждущий режим, однако тухнит экран, и когда я нажимаю клавишу на мыши или клавиатуре, то ПК включается. Я надеюсь, так и должно быть?